# how can we use join concept in mongodb using spring framework

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, microservices

I am new to spring framework recent i have made small project on microservices, where i create two microservices

1. department service
2. User service

I need to know how can i use join in them, i have create one common field in both the service i.e departmentId,
when i use getmapping in user service containing department id fetching the data from department service in respective to that departmentId.

Using intellij, mongodb as database, spring framework,java

Comment: u can use feign client to call one service to another

Answer (score 0):

Since mongo is a document store type database.
It depends on how the data will be used. You'll need to think how the data will be queried, what will the response may be.

In a RDBMS, it is natural to denormalize your data and split it over several tables and use joins to create the views you need.

In a document store you do exactly the opposite you'll normalize your data and try to include as much as you can to satisfy most queries in one query.

When you use spring, you might also like to use https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb

If you want to gain in-depth knowledge on mongo, they have several courses available where they can teach you for free: https://university.mongodb.com/